# Google Play Service issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I am working in eclipse for one project. I was facing issue in admob Native Ads, so I have tried to update google play service and marked that there no lib project available in sdk folder. That folder only contains sample and docs folder only. I have old library but its not working with admob. How can I get library project or jar file for google play service revision 30 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

To make the Google Play services APIs available to your app:

Copy the library project at /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ to the location where you maintain your Android app projects.
Import the library project into your Eclipse workspace. Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to import it.
In your app project, reference Google Play services library project. See Referencing a Library Project for Eclipse for more information on how to do this.

Note: You should be referencing a copy of the library that you copied to your development workspace—you should not reference the library directly from the Android SDK directory.
After you've added the Google Play services library as a dependency for your app project, open your app's manifest file and add the following tag as a child of the  element:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Once you've set up your project to reference the library project, you can begin developing features with the Google Play services APIs.
Create a ProGuard Exception

To prevent ProGuard from stripping away required classes, add the following lines in the /proguard-project.txt file:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final *** CREATOR;
}

-keep @interface android.support.annotation.Keep
-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class *
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
  @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keep @interface com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi
-keep public @com.google.android.gms.common.util.DynamiteApi class * {
  public <fields>;
  public <methods>;
}

-dontwarn android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy
```